# Google Maps API: Different formats of place_id value

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using getQueryPredictions method to get autofill entries. The value of `place_id` in about 10% of returned places is a 40 characters long string that starts with "E". I'm trying to pass that `place_id` to `google.maps.DistanceMatrixService().getDistanceMatrix` method to get a distance between those places and other "normal" locations but Google does not return anything for such IDs.

You can easily get such "E" `place_id` if you use address "4498 INTERSTATE NORTH PARKWAY EAST SOUTHEAST" at [this form from Map API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) It returns "EjM0NDk4IEludGVyc3RhdGUgTiBQa3d5IEUgU0UsIEF0bGFudGEsIEdBIDMwMzM5LCBVU0E" as `place_id`. Use that ID in any other Maps API mathods and Google won't recognize it as a valid place_id.

How can I use those weird IDs to look up distances? Or how can I transform them into normal `place_ids`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an API key and used the referred `place_id`, which returned a valid response.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=EjM0NDk4IEludGVyc3RhdGUgTiBQa3d5IEUgU0UsIEF0bGFudGEsIEdBIDMwMzM5LCBVU0E&key=[API_KEY]
```

Its not specified, but [not all Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id) can be used with `place_id`.

> You can use the same place ID across the Google Places API and a number of Google Maps APIs. For example, you can use the same place ID to reference a place in the Places API, the Google Maps JavaScript API, the Google Maps Geocoding API, the Google Maps Embed API and the Google Maps Roads API.

For your `getDistanceMatrix` to work, your `destinations[]` should either be string, `LatLng`, or `Place` objects. You'll have to use the `place_id` to get the place details (which has the `LatLng` that you can use for `getDistanceMatrix`).